# How can I run a KDE plasma script from command line without GUI?

Tags: scripting, kde, d-bus

I want to run a plasma JavaScript file from command line, but the only solution I found so far involves a graphical script editor and requires a user interaction to run the script:

```
qdbus org.kde.plasma-desktop /MainApplication loadScriptInInteractiveConsole "$PLASMA_SCRIPT_FILE"
```

Is there any solution that does not require a user interaction?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can (several places link to this question so I'm anwering here). Just use:

```
qdbus org.kde.plasmashell /PlasmaShell org.kde.PlasmaShell.evaluateScript
```

It takes a **script**, not a path for it, so valid use is for example:

```
qdbus org.kde.plasmashell /PlasmaShell org.kde.PlasmaShell.evaluateScript 'var foo = 1;'
```

Comment: Good to know that it's finally done! It's not available in Plasma 5.6 (from kubuntu 16.04 ppa), but kubuntu LTS users can use the http://archive.neon.kde.org repository to get shiny new plasma 5.8 where it works. (Note: upgrading kubuntu to KDE neon might break things, althought it did not for me.)

Answer (score -1):

```
qdbus org.kde.plasmashell /PlasmaShell org.kde.PlasmaShell.showInteractiveConsole
```

Answer (score -1):

Want to pick up on this old thread again.
However, under Ubuntu 22.04 and the KDE Plasma.

I want to run a plasma JavaScript file from command line too.
Have Found the Developer Site on

```
https://develop.kde.org/docs/extend/plasma/scripting/
```

but i cannot test this sample.

When I use the code from author, I get the error message

```
Cannot find '.loadScriptInInteractiveConsole' in object /MainApplication at org.kde.plasma-desktop
```

On Kamil's instruction I get the error

```
cannot find 'org.kde.PlasmaShell.showInteractiveConsole' in object /PlasmaShell at org.kde.plasmashell
```

Where and how do the scripts have to be provided to be executed via the command line?

Does anyone know a good site on which the basics are well explained ?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/421524)